# Prove/disprove the following asymptotic bound

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, asymptotics

Indicating with $p$ and $q$ prime numbers, is it true that for $x\rightarrow\infty$
$$
\sum_{\substack{p\leq x \\ p\equiv 1 \mod{m}}}\prod_{q\mid\frac{p-1}{m}}\left(1+\frac1{q}\right)2^{\omega\left(\frac{p-1}{m}\right)}
\ll \log\log x \sum_{\substack{p\leq x \\ p\equiv 1 \mod{m}}} 
\tau\left(\frac{p-1}{m}\right) \;,
$$
where $\tau(n)$ is the divisor function and $\omega(n)$ counts the number of primes dividing $n$?

I tried in this way: first, $2^{\omega\left(\frac{p-1}{m}\right)}
\leq \tau\left(\frac{p-1}{m}\right)$, but then using Mertens' third theorem
$$
\prod_{q\mid\frac{p-1}{m}}\left(1+\frac1{q}\right) = 
\prod_{q\mid\frac{p-1}{m}}\left(1-\frac1{q^2}\right)\left(1-\frac1{q}\right)^{-1}
\leq O(1)\prod_{q\leq\frac{p-1}{m}}\left(1-\frac1{q}\right)^{-1} =O\left( \log\left(\frac{p-1}{m}\right)\right)
$$
and I can't retrieve the $\log\log x$ term. Am I doing something wrong? Any suggestion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that $$\prod_{q\leq x}\left(1+\frac{1}{q}\right)\sim\log\left(x\right)
 $$ and $$\sum_{q\leq x}\left(1+\frac{1}{q}\right)\sim x+\log\left(\log\left(x\right)\right)
 $$ then $$\prod_{q\mid\left(p-1\right)/m}\left(1+\frac{1}{q}\right)\ll\sum_{q\mid\left(p-1\right)/m}\left(1+\frac{1}{q}\right)\leq\frac{3}{2}\omega\left(\frac{p-1}{m}\right)
 $$ and using the well-knonw bound $$\omega\left(a\right)\ll\log\left(\log\left(a\right)\right)
 $$ we have $$\frac{3}{2}\omega\left(\frac{p-1}{m}\right)\ll\log\left(\log\left(\frac{p-1}{m}\right)\right)\ll\log\left(\log\left(x\right)\right).
 $$

Comment: Thanks Marco! Need to convince about the inequality with the 3/2$\omega$ but I'm sure it's ok! Great job! ;)

Comment: @PITTALUGA I only took the maximum of $\left(1+\frac{1}{q}\right)$, then when $q=2$, multiplied the number of distinct primes dividing $(p-1)/m$. The sum is over those primes, then we have an upper bound.

Comment: all right, thanks a lot! Just one question: in your opinion, is it equivalent to prove it using the following Theorem 328 in Hardy&Wright (introduction to the theory of numbers): $\liminf (\varphi(n)\log\log n)/n=e^{-\gamma} $?

Comment: @PITTALUGA Yes, we can take the Euler's product for $\phi(n)$ and using the lower bound, $n>2$, $\approx n/(\log(\log\left(n\right))+c).$